# What is the physical intuition for the definition of elliptic PDE's?

Tags: mathematical-physics, soft-question

Consider the Laplace equation 
$$\Delta u=0.$$
I am aware of the relation of this equation to electrostatics, and that one can "guess" many of its mathematical properties from this physical framework. For instance, it is reasonable to expect uniqueness for the Dirichlet problem for the Laplace equation if we think of $u$ as a potential.

However, although I know of mathematical properties/theorems about general elliptic PDE's, I don't know if they have a physical interpretation which (like the potential interpretation for the Laplace equation) may allow us to expect that a lot of properties carry over.

That said, my question is: Is there a physical interpretation for the definition of elliptic PDE's? If so, does this help us to have some ground to expect some results?

Comment: This question is too general. The Laplace-equation appears in countless areas of physics, each time the quantity $u$ means something different. Mathematics is not about taking a physical quantity as a basis for a mathematical development. On the contrary, abstracting from the particular sense of $u$ assuming mathematical properties, conclusions are drawn.  Certainly one of the few things which can be learnt from physics about $u$ is that if the boundary conditions are analytical, the solutions are also analytical. If the mathematics can't reproduce this something has gone wrong.